# how to implement customized LdapAuthoritiesPopulator

Tags: spring, spring-security

This is some part of my spring-security.xml.
My requirement is - i want to use embedded LDAP server only and want to use LdapAuthoritiesPopulator with itt

```
<security:authentication-manager>
            <security:ldap-authentication-provider  
                    user-search-filter="(uid={0})" 
                    user-search-base="ou=users"
                    group-search-filter="(uniqueMember={0})"
                    group-search-base="ou=groups"
                    group-role-attribute="cn"
                    role-prefix="ROLE_">
            </security:ldap-authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>

    <!-- Use an embedded LDAP server. We need to declare the location of the LDIF file
            We also need to customize the root attribute default is -->
    <security:ldap-server ldif="classpath:mojo.ldif" root="dc=springframework,dc=org"/>
```

I want to use my custom LdapAuthoritiesPopulator. 
How to use it with embedded ldap server.
I am new to spring as of now.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure your authentication provider with DefaultLDAPAuthoritesPopulator and provide the details to find the groups for roles. If there is something more specific to your case, you could extend this class. Looking at the spring-security-samples. I am new to spring-security too but i found the source code to be very helpful. Good luck.

FYI
contextSource bean DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource should be configured with the url to your LDAP server.

Hope this helps.

```
<bean id="ldapAuthenticationProvider" class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.LdapAuthenticationProvider">
   <constructor-arg>
       <bean class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.BindAuthenticator">
            <constructor-arg ref="contextSource"/>
                <property name="userSearch">
                    <bean id="userSearch" class="org.springframework.security.ldap.search.FilterBasedLdapUserSearch">
                       <constructor-arg index="0" value="ou=Google,ou=People"/>
                       <constructor-arg index="1" value="(uid={0})"/>
                       <constructor-arg index="2" ref="contextSource"/>
                    </bean>
                </property>
       </bean>
   </constructor-arg>
   <constructor-arg>
        <bean class="org.springframework.security.ldap.userdetails.DefaultLdapAuthoritiesPopulator">
              <constructor-arg ref="contextSource"/>
              <constructor-arg value="ou=Groups"/>
              <property name="groupSearchFilter" value="member={0}"/>
              <property name="searchSubtree" value="true"/>
        </bean>
   </constructor-arg>
   <property name="authoritiesMapper">
         <bean class="org.springframework.security.core.authority.mapping.SimpleAuthorityMapper">
                <property name="convertToUpperCase" value="true"/>
          </bean>
    </property>
</bean>

 <bean id="contextSource" class="org.springframework.security.ldap.DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource">
    <constructor-arg value="ldap://127.0.0.1:389/dc=google,dc=com"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: what can be the conextSource for embedded server. Can you please give it ?